# executemany() with list of lists using cx_Oracle and xlrd in Python is returning TypeError

Tags: python, xlrd, cx-oracle, executemany

I am trying to write a Python script that will read data from an Excel document and then write it to a single table in an Oracle database. I am currently using `xlrd` to read from the Excel doc and `cx_Oracle` to insert the data into the database.

I had previously done this using a nested for-loop structure to go through every column in the Excel doc, store each column value in a variable, insert the values into the table, and then do this for every row. However, this was rather inefficient for a few thousand rows of data, and I am looking to do it using the `executemany()` statement with cx_Oracle

I am currently using this code to load the data into a list of lists and then calling the executemany() command:

```
rows = [] 
for rownum in range (sh1.nrows):
        column_value = sh1.row_values(rownum)
        EMPLOYEE = column_value[1]
        ITEM_DATE = column_value[2]
        HOURS = column_value[3]
        row = [EMPLOYEE, ITEM_DATE, HOURS]
        rows.append(row)

query ="""INSERT INTO TABLE1 (EMPLOYEE, ITEM_DATE, HOURS) VALUES (:1, :2, :2)"""
# executemany by passing list rows with tuples (EMPLOYEE, ITEM_DATE, HOURS)
cursor.executemany(query, rows)
```

The rows list looks like this:

```
[[u'Employee 1', 10000.0, 8.0], [u'Employee 1', 10001.0, 8.0], [u'Employee 1', 10002.0, 8.0]....]
# I have disguised the names and numbers here
```

However, I am getting a type error when the executemany() statement is being executed:

```
cursor.executemany(query, rows)
TypeError: expecting string, unicode or buffer object
```

The query executes perfectly fine when performing an `cursor.execute(query, row)` (doing a single insert on the last row of data read), so I presume there is something wrong with the way the list of parameters are formatted, not the query string.  However, my parameters appear correctly formatted according to [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/cx-oracle-demos/source/browse/trunk/executemany.py?r=10) Can anybody help me understand why my code is not working?

**Update:** So I tried manually inserting some data into the `rows` variable to see if my formatting was off, and took off the unicode character:

```
rows = [['Employee 1', 10000.0, 8.0], ['Employee 1', 10001.0, 8.0], ['Employee 1', 10002.0, 8.0]]
```

Inserting these three entries worked just fine, so I am currently investigating the unicode character as the cause of the problem. Any help would still be appreciated.

Comment: I am having similar issue, but haven't been able to make it work. Do you know what could be wrong here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238423/python-cx-oracle-expecting-string-unicode-or-buffer-object?noredirect=1#comment39317797_25238423

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the unicode was the entire problem. I used `print type(EMPLOYEE)` in the for-loop and confirmed that the employee name was being encoded with unicode whereas the database was simply expecting an ascii string. I converted the value using the `str()` function and everything worked correctly. The only downside to this is that the `str()` command will throw an error if there are actually unicode characters in the employee name, so I will soon be looking into actually converting the string to handle unicode characters.